# Hice 2 tarjetas que desliza texto , pero se mueven todas al mismo tiempo en vez de una sola

Tags: html, css, card

Hice 3 tarjetas que deberían deslizar un texto para abajo cada vez que uno posiciona el *mouse*. Lo hacen, pero en vez de hacerlo individualmente, las otras que no están siendo seleccionadas, mueven el fondo abajo en vez de quedarse estáticas.

Es como que hace el movimiento en columna, pero estando una al lado de la otra en pantalla completa.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #16384c;
}

h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  justify-content: ;
  color: sandybrown;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 1100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 30px;
  top: 120px;
}

.container .card {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 300px;
  height: 215px;
  background-color: sandybrown;
  margin: 30px 10px;
  padding: 20px 15px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 202px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.container .card:hover {
  height: 420px;
}

.container .card .imgbx {
  position: relative;
  width: 260px;
  height: 260px;
  top: -60px;
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.container .card .imgbx img {
  max-width: 100%;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.container .card .content {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -140px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  color: brown;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.container .card:hover .content {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  margin-top: -40px;
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
</head>
<H1>BIENVENIDOS A AMBAR DECO</H1>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="imgbx">
        <img src="/imagenes/ambar tarjeta.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <h2>Card one</h2>
        <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum, eaque sint magni accusantium nesciunt explicabo quasi esse, cumque non corporis est ratione eum rem! Harum blanditiis quae mollitia beatae dicta.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="imgbx">
        <img src="/imagenes/ambar.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <h2>Card two</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio excepturi veniam a sint sunt? Facere, est aspernatur aperiam, blanditiis quos animi corporis sapiente nostrum perferendis libero ex quisquam laboriosam consectetur!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="imgbx">
        <img src="/imagenes/komondor.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <h2>Card Three</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Dicta aliquid rem a laboriosam. Eveniet esse eaque, reprehenderit molestias dolor impedit minus, laboriosam quidem necessitatibus vel similique exercitationem explicabo non consectetur!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Deberías agregar también tu **HTML5**,  el ```container``` y ```card```, para comparar y hallar el problema. Porque la función que quieres con **CSS** es muy fácil

Comment: Gracias. ya agregué el html

Comment: Puedes convertir tu código a snippet, pulsando en el botón que indica `<>` o con `Ctrl + M`.

Comment: Hola, Emiliano, coloqué el código en un Snippet para que pueda reproducirse y eliminé párrafos duplicados.

Comment: gracias x tu tiempo.

Comment: El efecto que quiero lograr, copie y creí entender fue el de este video. Al flaco le sale, pero a mi no, igualmente ya estuve copiando, analizando varios videos de este flaco y no siempre funcionan, debo cambiarle cosas no se por que... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uR7EbQImYmo&list=PLU9ugz5xCf8IwY2wgKYHBrFjumo-i2o7Z&index=8&t=20s

Answer (score 0):

La solución sería saber definir el estilo y transición de cada elemento. Ice un cambio radical en tu estilo deduciendo y tratando de entender tu pregunta.

Al hacer `hover` en **card**, Ice lo siguiente:

- Aparece desde arriba hacia abajo la clase: **content**
- La clase **card** crece verticalmente
- El contenedor de la imagen **imgbx** se redimenciona con `scale`

Todo esto (excepto el `:hover` que está comentado) hace que no se expanda los demás div's de la **card**. Si se habilita la parte comentada si crece la **card** empujando los demás div's.

```css
* {
  /* Es importante todo esto */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  outline: none;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #16384c;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 1100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 20px;
  top: 120px;
}

.container .card {
  overflow: hidden;
  /* para ocultar .card */
  position: relative;
  max-width: 300px;
  height: 215px;
  background-color: sandybrown;
  margin: 30px 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}


/* habilitar para otra transicion */


/* .container .card:hover {
 height: 420px;
} */

.container .card .imgbx {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.container .card:hover .imgbx {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.container .card .imgbx img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.container .card .content {
  position: absolute;
  /* sobre .card */
  z-index: 1;
  top: -100%;
  /* fuera de .card */
  left: 5%;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 90%;
  height: calc(100% - 10%);
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  color: yellow;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: rgba(244, 164, 96, .7);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.container .card:hover .content {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  top: 5%;
  /* no es necesario una transición */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="imgbx">
      <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/02/27/16/10/tree-276014_640.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <h2>Card one</h2>
      <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum, eaque sint magni accusantium nesciunt explicabo quasi esse, cumque non corporis est ratione eum rem! Harum blanditiis quae mollitia beatae dicta.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias por la edición. No pude hacer bien desde el móvil